# Late Answers review queue has audits-only

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, late-answers

Basically, title says it all: [25 reviewed late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) on a Wednesday morning (German time) - and all of them audits (on the bright side, nearly all of of them passed).

Audits-only started a bit before midnight, [last "real"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/1752382).

Bug or feature?

**Edit**: still stuck, so the *last real* above marks the absolute time it started.

**Edit2** and **bump**:

bug seems to be back again, audits-only since [last "real" review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/1959996) - this is rather suboptimal as the late-answers are accumulating (causing yet another review stampede whenever it will be resolved) - anybody listening?

**Edit3**

review queue stuck again, [last real](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2601682) - wondering why this seems to be happening to the late answers only? The answers are fed into to first posts queue (if they are first as well as late)

Comment: Is this a 10k only? I wasn't able to see anything related to audits.

Comment: @AbZy hmm ... don't know: I see the type of review by opening the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history) and then click on a link of the second-last column

Comment: When I click that link, I see only my reviews.

Comment: @Ren - thanks, then it really seems to be a >10k (or >20k, don't remember when I started seeing them)

Comment: No problem. I've managed 7 now just opening the queue to see if there was anything in it even without the review page saying so. They were all audits though. Going to stop as I think the queue is indeed bugged.

Comment: @Ren and all passed, of course - good job :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was optimizing the SQL yesterday to lessen the server pain on these reviews and make them run faster...however when you put 2 Ids in the query backwards it doesn't work very well at all.

A fix will be built out in the next few minutes to get this queue going again.

Comment: "...it doesn't work very well at all." But they did run faster, right?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby - 10.2mil reads down to a little over 2k and ~8,600ms of CPU down to ~120ms, so yep