# Late answers review queue - bug or coincidence

Tags: bug, review, late-answers

I've been polling for reviews of late answers on SO for about 6 hours now, and the only answers I've got were the test ones. The recent reviews list stays the same for hours and changes by a single answer (and I suspect it's also about the test answers).

[The stats for today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) show a similar story. There are only 2 people who managed to review 4 answers.

Is it incredibly slow day and just a coincidence or is there some kind of a bug in the late answers queue?

Comment: I've managed 6 now just opening the queue to see if there was anything in it even without the review page saying so. They were all audits though.

Comment: I've been trying the same thing for the last 6 hours and all I managed to get was 2 reviews, both test ones..

Comment: See this also -http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172631/late-answers-review-queue-has-audits-only-for-10-hrs?rq=1